# How to pass NULL value in ajax jquery call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I have a problem with my Ajax post call. I have two fields one for amount and one for Datetime. I want to be able to pass both values as null values and the program shouldn't crash. My C# method head look like this

```
public ActionResult Update(int invoiceNumber, DateTime start,decimal payAmount = 0)
```

And my Jquery code look like this

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".changeInvoice", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var invoiceNr = $("#invoiceNumber").val();
        var start = $("#date").val();
        var payAmount = $("#payAmount").val();
        console.log(invoiceNr);

        var updateInvoice =
        {
            invoiceNumber: invoiceNr,
            start: start,
            payAmount: payAmount
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "URL",
            data: updateInvoice,
            success: function (response) {
                location.reload();

            }
        });
```

If i run the program now its crashes if a user doesn't fill in the start datetime value. But if i set a Datetime? start in my C# code the valdidation works without a crash but then i cant do this in my C# code. As i have understood you cant add days to a nullable datetime variable. Any Suggestions?:

```
i.FirstReminderDate = start.Date.AddDays(10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to convert the datetime value after i had set an nullable Datetime as parameter so:

```
   public ActionResult Update(int invoiceNumber, DateTime? start,decimal payAmount = 0)
{
    i.FirstReminderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(start).Date.AddDays(10);
}
```

And with that everything worked

Answer (score 0):

and depending when you want to set your initial date, also can be 10 days from today, becasue the default date is : 1/11/0001 12:00:00 AM, there is no sense to add 10 days to this date, but if you want to set the initial date like today can be something like

```
DateTime firstReminderDateFromToday = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(10);

if (start != null)
    i.firstReminderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(start).Date.AddDays(10);
else
    i.firstReminderDate = firstReminderDateFromToday;
```

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thank you!